# Linear antenna: with electromagnetic coil, trap circuit

Tags: current, antenna, coil, linear, dipole

I am trying to understand the concept of the linear antennas.
I have read that the linear antennas are the simplest form of the antenna in the case of asymmetrical (coaxial) feed.

what happens if I add the coil?

[image]

or circuit?

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: You need to ask a much more specific question. At the moment your questions (and their breadth of scale) would require an answer as big as a book.

Comment: @ I changed the quaston

Comment: Where is the coaxial (unbalanced) feed point you refer to?

Comment: @Andyaka i added

Comment: I don't understand the bottom left diagram - why have you added a parallel tuned circuit?

Comment: @Andyaka i found this picture (Bild 11-28:) here [link](https://www.darc.de/der-club/referate/ajw/lehrgang-te/e11/)